# Symfony2 handleRequest with PUT request

Tags: symfony, put

I have some trouble with handleRequest:

Here is my code:

```
public function putAssetAction(Request $request, $id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository( 'BudgetBundle:Asset' )->find( $id );
    $form = $this->createForm( new AssetType(), $entity, array('method' => 'PUT') );
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

The problem is that form data are correct, but `$form->isValid()` return `false` because `isSubmitted()` is `false`

But `$form->bind()` is also not working, because it's a PUT request, and when I do `bind($request)` then `$form->getData()` returns `null`.

I'm using this with FosRestBundle and Backbone, and for testing request I'm using chrome extension postman.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `submit()` instead of `handleRequest()`, eg:

```
$form->submit($request);
```

Comment: Thx, but when I do submit then $form->getData() returns entity with only id, other paramaters are empty.

Comment: What do you mean? It is set to `PUT`. `$this->createForm( new AssetType(), $entity, array('method' => 'PUT') )`

Comment: You should really use `$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()));` as handling the `Request` directly is deprecated. It still works but won't in the future (3.0 definitely).

Comment: @Qoop that is why I try to use `handleRequest`, in this case your code return null.